# How does % in Makefiles work?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to understand how makefiles work. If I try the following

```
1.out : 1.inp
    cat 1.inp
```

it, works as expected (if 1.inp is newer as 1.out or if 1.out does not exist, the content of 1.inp is printed).

Then I need to do the following:

```
cat 1.inp
cat 2.inp
cat 3.inp
```

I thought that for that I can use

```
%.out : %.inp
    cat $<
```

but it does not work. Can anybody please explain to me the use of `%`?

Comment: Do you want to understand `%`, or do you want to print the contents of the new `inp` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first makefile:

```
1.out: 1.inp
    cat 1.inp
```

`1.out` is a *target* with a *prerequisite* `1.inp` and a *command* `cat 1.inp`. This constitutes a *rule* for
making `1.out` and if you run the makefile, specifying either no explicit target or the target `1.out`, the
rule will be executed.

In your second makefile:

```
%.out: %.inp
    cat $<
```

you have only expressed a *pattern rule* for making a target of the form *something*.out from a prerequisite of the form *something*.inp *You have not specified any actual targets that the makefile can make*.

You can specify `1.out` as a target with a makefile like this:

```
%.out: %.inp
    cat $<

1.out:
```

In that case `1.inp` will be `cat`-ed when `1.inp` is newer that `1.out`

Or you can specify a *phony* target, e.g. `all`, that has prerequisite targets `1.out`, `2.out`, `3.out` in a makefile like this:

```
.PHONY: all

%.out: %.inp
    cat $<

all: 1.out 2.out 3.out
```

In this case each of `1.inp`, `2.inp` and `3.inp` will be `cat`-ed when it is newer than the corresponding `.out` file.

Whenever make discovers that it has to make a target of the form *something*.out, it will recognize that the *pattern rule* is applicable and will execute the matching instance of the pattern rule.

Comment: You can also directly specify the targets of interest on the command line: `make 1.out 2.out 3.out` will produce the desired output without adding anything in the `Makefile`